# Videojs HLS not working

Tags: html, streaming, video.js, http-live-streaming

I am trying to stream HLS media trough videojs, but its not working.

I am aware that desktop browsers do not support HLS, but its not working on android/ios devices also...

I get an error: **no compatible source was found for this video**

Can anyone take a look at my code, and spot any errors?

Streams are working on my local server, tested with VLC so problem must be somewhere on my configuration of videojs.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="http://belelros.github.io/videojs-playLists/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://belelros.github.io/videojs-playLists/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.9/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.9/video.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/Belelros/videojs-playLists/master/lib/videojs-playlists.js" data-cover></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="main.js"></script>

</head>
    <div class="video-holder centered">

        <video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
               controls preload="auto" width="640" height="640"
               data-setup=''
               poster="">
        </video>

        <div class="playlist-components">
<script>
     var videos = [
        {
          src : [
            'http://192.168.1.165/streamtest1.m3u8'
          ],
          poster : 'images/bbc_news.png',
          title : 'BBC WORLD NEWS'
        },
        {
          src : [
            'http://192.168.1.165/streamtest2.m3u8'
          ],
          poster : 'images/al_jazeera_english.png',
          title : 'AL JAZEERA'
        },
        {
          src : [
            'http://192.168.1.165/streamtest3.m3u8'
          ],
          poster : 'images/viasat_explore.png',
          title : 'Viasat Explore'
        }
      ];
</script>

            <div class="playlist">
                <ul></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I am using a playlist plugin for videojs
https://github.com/jgallen23/videojs-playLists

Maybe i should define video type somewhere?

Comment: When i remove playlist and use only one source, then it works fine.  <source src="streamtest1.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">  How can i define content type if i want to use playlist.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it, added m3u8 extension to videojs-playlist.js

```
  player.pl._guessVideoType = function(video){
var videoTypes = {
  'webm' : 'video/webm',
  'mp4' : 'video/mp4',
  'm3u8' : 'application/x-mpegURL',
  'ogv' : 'video/ogg'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add hls support using following

```
npm install --save videojs-contrib-hls.js
```

OR 
Include videojs-contrib-hls.js from CDN.

```
https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls.js@3.2.0/dist/videojs-contrib-hlsjs.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Play HLS, DASH, and future HTTP streaming protocols with video.js, even where they're not natively supported.

Included in video.js 7 by default!

[have a look here](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. –